# Разбить на части JSON

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, post

Есть объект json такого вида:

```js
{
"1":{"id":"1","price":"60","qty":"56"},
"4":{"id":"4","price":"85","qty":"23"},
"2":{"id":"2","price":"53","qty":"11"}
}
```

Это возврат $.post из обработчика на PHP.

Как вывести каждую строку отдельно циклом?

И for пробовал, и for..in.

Ключ — число, и из-за этого тоже загвоздка у меня. Как обратиться к price при `id=4`?

Comment: Покажите пожалуйста цикл, который у вас не получается

Comment: Я видимо поторопился с вопросом тут. Косяк где-то в формировании json.

Comment: json  как  json...

Answer (score 1):

Пример итерации и получение значения по ключу

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yejeXX

```
var jsonData = {"1":{"id":"1","price":"60","qty":"56"}, "4":{"id":"4","price":"85","qty":"23"}, "2":{"id":"2","price":"53","qty":"11"}}

$.each(jsonData, function(key, val) {
  $('body').append($('<p>').text('key:'+key+', price:'+val.price));
});

$('body').append('<h4>Price for 4 key is: '+jsonData["4"].price+'</h4>')
```

Для `$.post` укажите тип данных который принимает `callback`

```
$.post('action', function(data) { 
  console.log(data); 
}, 'json');
```

Comment: Ага, а если не указать тип - всегда можно полученную строку преобразовать через JSON.parse(string)

Answer (score 0):

Так. Есть у нас объект.

```
var test = {
"1":{"id":"1","price":"60","qty":"56"},
"4":{"id":"4","price":"85","qty":"23"},
"2":{"id":"2","price":"53","qty":"11"}
};
```

Отвечу на последний вопрос для начала.

Чтобы обратиться к элементу с числовым ключом - достаточно записать это так, как-будто вы обращаетесь к ассоциативному массиву по ключу. Т.е. к элементу с ключом 4 можно обратиться так: `test[4]`

Теперь к первому вопросу.
Так как это не упорядоченный массив, где ключи начинаются с 0, то конечно проще сделать цикл for..in, который пробегает по всем элементам.

Он будет выглядеть просто:

```
for (var i in test) {
    console.log(test[i]);
};
```

где i - это ключ, и, как следует из первой части моего ответа: `test[i]` обращение к элементу объекта по ключу.

В итоге в консоли можно будет увидеть

```
Object {id: "1", price: "60", qty: "56"}
Object {id: "2", price: "53", qty: "11"}
Object {id: "4", price: "85", qty: "23"}
```

Ну и конечно пробегаясь в цикле, чтоб достать значения можно обращаться уже к ключам через привычную точку: `test[i].id` или `test[i].price` и так далее

Answer (score 0):

А поему бы на `BackEnd'e` этого перед выводом не сделать?

```
$elements = 5;
$results = array_chunk($results, $elements);

echo json_encode($results);
```

Оно Вам вернет масиив объекто, в котором находится по 5 элементов в каждом.